# BigQuery/Gcp data transfer to Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to transfer data from a table in BigQuery, into Amazon S3.

My planned data flow is as follows:
**BigQuery -> Google Cloud Storage -> Amazon S3.**

I know about Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service, but I'm not sure it can help me as according to google documentation it can be used only to import data into gcp.

I tried using the gsutils and it is working, but i wanted to know, if there is a way to achieve this using any java api.

Comment: Look at the Java SDK APIs for both GCP and AWS. Basically, you are just doing a read from one bucket and writing to another bucket. Lot's of examples on the Internet for both services.

Comment: @JohnHanley, the sdk allows me to download the file to a local server, but i could not find anything that helps me to transfer from cloud to cloud. Can you suggest anything to help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Look at the Java SDK APIs for both GCP and AWS. Basically, you are just doing a read from one bucket and writing to another bucket. Lot's of examples on the Internet for both services